# WAN Woes Between Satellite Offices

Tags: networking, vpn, route, wide-area-network

Having a baffling time trying to troubleshoot an issue between 3 sites on a WAN set up via site-to-site VPN.

The sites are:

- NY:   10.30.1.0  (HQ)
- OH:   10.30.6.0
- CT:   10.30.7.0

When I first started working on it, the OH and CT sites are able to communicate to NY with traffic going both ways, no problem.

After some troubleshooting on their Fortinet firewalls, I essentially added site-to-site VPN entries between the two satellite sites (OH + CT).   That proved somewhat successful as I am now able to communicate from CT to OH with no issues.

The problem I'm encountering is from OH to CT--it cannot contact anything within their network.  Pinging servers resolves the IP addresses of the respective server in CT, but times out.  I'm pulling my hair out because I'm most likely overlooking something simple, but can't seem to pinpoint the issue.

I know the information I provided is rather vague--but please let me know if there are any questions that require more specific information and I'll try to provide them.

Comment: do a traceroute and see if there is anything odd about the path being taken.

Comment: Did 2 tracerts, one to NYHQ which took a total of 3 hops:  1 to the router, 1 resolved to NY external IP, last to internal server.

Second tracert to CT only managed to reach the first hop, OH's router.  The rest timed out.